# Eclipse notification when all JUnit tests run

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Running my tests recently takes quite a time (about 1-2 minutes), and I usually get discracted by something while waiting for them to finish.

Is there any way to make Eclipse give me a notification (e.g., playing a sound or something) when all of the tests are finished? I took a look on all possible settings in the run configuration of the JUnit runner, but haven't found anything I could use.

Creating a test named `xxx.XLastTest` that does the job could be a workaround, but I find that a bit ugly (it won't work if the tests run concurrently, and I don't even want to see it in our CI).

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any kind of notification option built-in, but it would be pretty easy to write a plugin yourself to do it. See the documentation for [TestRunListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/junit/TestRunListener.html).

[Here's an example](https://bitbucket.org/brettdaniel/junitmusicbox/src) of something similar, although it will be tough to install it into an Eclipse instance since there is no update site provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a test suite and get a notification in the end. On the CI server, don't run that test suite, but all other tests "standalone".

```java
@RunWith( Suite.class )
@SuiteClasses( { Test1.class, Test2.class } )
public class AllTests {
    @AfterClass
    public static void notifySleepyDeveloper() {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Tests are finished", "Test Suite", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my other first idea. The drawback is I have ~70 test classes, and I don't want to enumerate them nor constantly update the `@SuiteClasses` definition (I'm sure I'll forgot that).

Comment: Hm, thanks, gonna take a look on that. Probably I can do something with reflection...